# Obtaining related Ember model data from within a route or component

Tags: ember.js

**Update - partial solution - see below**

I have a (product category) model with a many to many relationship eg

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
 name: DS.attr('string'),
 products:DS.hasMany('product')
});
```

My category route (product.items) is backed by this model, and it's no problem displaying the related product data:

```
{{#each model.data.products as |item|}}
 {{item.name}}
{{/each}}
```

However, I need to obtain the related data within the child route (product.items.item). The model hook for the route looks like this:

```
model(params) {
  let parentModel = this.modelFor('product.items'),
  let model = this.store.findRecord('product',params.id);

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    data:model,
    parentData:parentModel
  });
}
```

I can then then pass this model to a component.

What I am trying to do is access that related within a component (or within the route). Assuming the model is available in the component as parentModel I can access the name of the parent category as

```
 let name = parentModel.data.get('name');
```

I thought I could do the same for the related products ie

```
 let products = parentModel.data.get('products');
```

However, this doesn't return anything. Am I making a basic mistake here?

The reason I want to access the other products in the parent category, when viewing an item, is that I want the user to paginate through each item.

Using the JSONAPIAdapter.

Many thanks in advance!

**Update**

This code does work when I navigate from the parent category - but not when you're on them item page and the app is refreshed on a code update - which is why I wasn't getting the expect results. So partially there! Will update if I can find a full solution!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why I can't access the related data on an app refresh when viewing the product item. I can still access (for example) the name of the category as indicated above, but if I return the length of the products array (which for example should be 5) I get zero. This is what was throwing me previously as I was always refreshing the app on the product detail (product.items.item) route!

Comment: Got this working now ... using the get call as a promise  which I what I need to do in my component eg mainModel.data.get(this.get('relatedModel')).then(relatedItems => {
      console.log(relatedItems.get('length'));
      relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
        console.log(item.get('name'));
      });

    },reject => {
      console.log('error: '+reject);
    });

Comment: You can answer your own question for posterity- go ahead and create an answer with your results and "accept" it.

Comment: Hi Steve H, I will do so - hope it helps other people and I have absolutely no doubt it could be improved upon !!! Will post it shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution - I'm sure it can be improved upon!

The purpose of my component is to allow the user to paginate through individual (product) item pages. The product category model has a many to many relationship with products as shown in the original question.

In my template (product/items/item.hbs) I call the component

```
{{pagination-item data=model relatedModel='products' route='product.items.item'}}
```

Where the model is the RSVP hash {data:itemModel,mainData:mainModel}. The itemModel is self explanatory; the mainModel is the category model.

Here is the component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName:'ul',
  pagination:null,

generate(itemSlug) {
  let page = {};
  let allData = this.get('data');
  let itemModel = allData.data; 
  let mainModel = allData.mainData;

  mainModel.data.get(this.get('relatedModel')).then(relatedItems => {
    let maxRecords = relatedItems.get('length');
    relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
      if (item.get('slug') === itemSlug) {
        if (index === 0) {
          page.Prev = null;
          page.Next = relatedItems.objectAt(index+1).get('slug');
        }
        else if (index+1 === maxRecords) {
          page.Prev = relatedItems.objectAt(index-1).get('slug');
          page.Next = null;
        }
        else {
          page.Prev = relatedItems.objectAt(index-1).get('slug');
          page.Next = relatedItems.objectAt(index+1).get('slug');
        }
      }
    });
    this.set('pagination',page);
  },reject => {
    console.log('error: '+reject);
  });
},
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  let allData = this.get('data');
  let itemModel = allData.data;
  this.generate(itemModel.get('id'));
},
click(event) {
  let target = Ember.$(event.target);
  let pathname = target.context.pathname;
  let slug = pathname.split("/").reverse()[0];
  this.generate(slug);
}
});
```

In the template for the component pagination-item.hbs I have

```
{{#each-in pagination as |key value|}}
{{#if value}}
<li>{{link-to key route value}}</li>
{{/if}}
{{/each-in}}
```

I assume it's better to crate another component for the li and then handle the click as an action on that and pass the value to the child component rather than doing it the way I am in the parent component?

Hope this helps!