# Ember: Setting a component object value within a promise

Tags: ember.js

I have component with a couple of properties, using a promise in the willRender hook to try and create a (pagination) object:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   pagination:null,
   testing:null, // to check if this.set is ok within the promise!
   willRender() {
      let page = {};
      let model = this.get('data');
      model.get('products').then(relatedItems => {    
          let maxRecords = relatedItems.get('length');
          relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
              if (item.get('slug') === itemModel.get('id')) {
                if (index === 0) {
                  page.Prev = null;
                  page.Next = relatedItems.objectAt(index+1).get('slug');
                }
               else if (index+1 === maxRecords) {
                 page.Prev = relatedItems.objectAt(index-1).get('slug');
                 page.Next = null;
               }
            else {
               page.Prev = relatedItems.objectAt(index-1).get('slug');
               page.Next = relatedItems.objectAt(index+1).get('slug');
             }
            }
          });
          this.set('testing','hello world');
          console.log(this.get('testing')); // hello world
          this.set('pagination',page);
          console.log(this.get('pagination')); // Object {Prev: "product-1", Next: "product-2"}

      },reject => {
          console.log('error '+reject);
      });
   }
})
```

In my template

```
{{testing}} // prints hello world
```

However, if I try and access {{pagination}} eg {{log pagination}}, the browser crashes with a loop printing out the object to the console.

I don't know where I'm going wrong here - any help much appreciated!

Comment: What is the message you got in the console ?

Comment: Hi - the console is just printing the object in a loop eg Object {Prev: "product-1", Next: "product-2"} etc etc etc etc

Comment: Can you paste the code of your template please ?

Comment: {{testing}} // prints hello world
{{log pagination}}

Comment: I'm not sure how this code works, it looks like there is a NPE `itemModel.get('id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely you are triggering the template to rerender causing `willRender` to fire over and over which causes an infinite loop in your code.

`willRender` is a non-standard place to do this code, `init` would be more standard since it only fires on initialization of the component. Even better would be to use

```
myInit: Ember.on('init', function(){ 
    .... 
})`
```

instead of overriding `willRender` on the object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. To be honest, I'm not very clear on the right way to use the component lifecycle hooks - didn't think the docs were that clear on it :-) I've tried init() and it doesn't produce the same problem. I think I need to think the component through again and introduce a click event so that I can re-reun the code which generates the pagination buttons ....  I should have tried this before !!

Comment: I totally understand, Ember is a framework with a lot of years under its belt, and learning it sometimes feels a bit like drinking from a fire hose, but it gets better :).

Comment: Hi, I feel like I'm getting there bit by bit :-) A detailed tutorial on the component life cycle wouldn't go amiss, and also event handling!! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Kingpin2k, I posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436089/obtaining-related-ember-model-data-from-within-a-route-or-component?noredirect=1#comment62441007_37436089 - I'm sure it can be improved upon!

Answer (score 0):

try to check whether Object is present at specific position. i think its going undefined during iteration of for loop. try to ensure that ObjectAt is not returning undefined or null value during running of for loop.

```
relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
          if (item.get('slug') === itemModel.get('id')) {
            if (index === 0) {
              page.Prev = null;
              if(relatedItems.objectAt(index+1) ! = undefined) {
                 page.Next = relatedItems.objectAt(index+1).get('slug');
               }else{
                   page.Next == null;
                    }
            }
           else if (index+1 === maxRecords) {
             if(relatedItems.objectAt(index-1) ! = undefined) {
                page.Prev = relatedItems.objectAt(index-1).get('slug');
              }else{
                page.Prev = null;
              }
             page.Next = null;
           }
        else {
          if(relatedItems.objectAt(index-1) ! = undefined) {
           page.Prev = relatedItems.objectAt(index-1).get('slug');
          }else{
               page.Prev = null;
           }
         if(relatedItems.objectAt(index+1) ! = undefined) {
           page.Next = relatedItems.objectAt(index+1).get('slug');
           }else{
               page.Next = null;
              }
         }
        }
```

Please ensure that Object at is returning object.

Comment: Hi - many thanks for this. Have edited my code but still get the same result with the object printed out in a loop

Comment: defined var _self = this; before .then callback. and use _self in replace of "this" within .then callback. like that
_self.set('pagination',page);

Comment: Please share the code where you call this component and template code where it is using pagination property.
may be your browser is crashing due to another issue.

Comment: Hi, what could be causing a problem in the willRender() hook is that it appears to be running twice.... if I console out model.get('name') before I run the promise in the original code, it gets printed out twice and to be honest, I'm not sure why! Could this be the problem?

Comment: Have tried - doesn't make a difference I'm afraid. I just don't understand why I can print the object out within the promise as shown in the original code but can't use it in my template.. I don't have anything else to share I'm afraid!

Comment: Hi, even if I remove the forEach loop and just set the pagination object in the promise, I get the same problem! ie model.data.get('products').then(relatedItems => {page.name = 'hello world'; this.set('pagination',page);},reject => {// as before});

Comment: ** model.get('products').then(relatedItems => {    } ) **
change the ECM6 sytax into like that

let _self = this;
model.get('products').then(function(products){
 _self.set('pagination', 'bla bla bla');
})

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few problems here, would be interested to know what your console errors are.

You don't seem to have defined `itemModel` so don't know how you're referencing that.

Also you can't access `this` from within a `.then`. You need to do something like this to set a component variable.

```
var _this = this;

promise().then(function(results) {
  _this.set('testing', 'hello world');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you are not using `,` after `testing:null` 
there should be `,` after testing property like that

```
pagination:null,
   testing:null, // i use ',' after testing: null property
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the code I wrote here - not the case in my real environment - will correct above

Comment: I didn't degrade it as far as I was aware and I certainly didn't do anything intentional I can assure you!

Answer (score -1):

try to use your pagination code under `init` hook rather than `willrender` hook

```
init() {
    //you code
  },
```

Comment: This works in that the object doesn't run in a loop, but is no good for the printing of the object as init() is only run once? {{#each-in pagination as |key value|}}
{{#if value}}
<li>{{link-to key route value}}</li>
{{/if}}
{{/each-in}}

Comment: something is wrong in relatedItems for Loop. share code of Foreach loop.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back. If there was something wrong with the forEach loop, would I be able to console out the object as I showed above? I will add the code to the original message

Comment: Please track the line from where error raise by using 'debugger' in forEach loop.

Comment: i already answered that you should run your logic in init hook of component but you said same results are producing. you should accept my answer because i spend much more time and already told you to use init hook of component :-(

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry about that - I felt Kingpin2k got to the point quicker and provided some additional info which has prompted me to look the code in a different way. I very much appreciate your help - if I can give you credit for your efforts I will (not sure how - is this possible?).